# Currying in Scala, what are the types that make these statements compile?

Tags: scala

So I have this function in Scala:

```
def f(a: Int)(b: Int)(c: Double)(d: Double): Double = a * c + b * d
```

The question is What are the three types that make the following statements compile.

```
def g: <Type1> = f(1)(2)(3.0) 
def h: <Type2> = f(1)(2) 
def k: <Type3> = f(1)
```

I'm still new to Scala and I am not really understanding the concept of currying. Maybe an answer to this question with some explanation will really help me. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried any types? What did the compiler tell you?

Comment: Is it a syntax problem or a semantic problem? Start with 'g'.

Comment: Is this homework?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, one main thing: function that takes two parameters `a` and `b` and returns a value `c` can be viewed as a function that takes an `a` and returns a function that takes `b` and returns `c`. This "change of point of view" is called currying.

Imagine a function that sums up two numbers. You give it 2 and 3, it returns 5. It can be viewed as a function that takes one number and returns a function from a number to a number. You give it a 2, it returns a function that takes some number and adds 2 to it.

Now, some types that you requested:

```
// pseudocode!

def g: Double => Double 
  = f(1)(2)(3.0) // we supply three params and are left with only one, "d"
  = (d: Double) => 1 * 3.0 + 2 * d // we comply with g's type

def h: Double => Double => Double // or (Double, Double) => Double 
  = f(1)(2) // we supply two params and are left with two more, "c" and "d"
  = (c: Double)(d: Double) => 1 * c + 2 * d // we comply with h's type

def k: Double => Double => Double => Double // or (Double, Double, Double) => Double
  = f(1) // we supply one param and are left with three more, "b", "c" and "d"
  = (b: Double)(c: Double)(d: Double) => 1 * c + b * d // we comply with k's type
```

Answer (score 0):

Currying IMO is one of the most confusing concepts in Scala. The term itself comes from functional programming paradigm and, according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), is

> the technique of translating the evaluation of a function that takes
>   multiple arguments (or a tuple of arguments) into evaluating a
>   sequence of functions, each with a single argument.

which means that function call `f(a, b, c)` is represented by `f(a)(b)(c)`. Looks like Scala? Not exactly. Here we have three function calls, each of them returns another function. Type of `f` (in Scala speak) is `Int => (Int => (Double => (Double => Double)))`. Let's look at your `f`:

```
scala> def f(a: Int)(b: Int)(c: Double)(d: Double): Double = a * c + b * d
f: (a: Int)(b: Int)(c: Double)(d: Double)Double
```

As you see, there are no arrows here. What we have here is a **method** with multiple parameter lists. Method has no value and can't be assigned or passed anywhere, it belongs to an object. Function, on the other hand, **is** an object and can be assigned or passed to another method or function. In most cases omitting parameter lists is not allowed for methods:

```
scala> f(0)
<console>:01: error: missing argument list for method f
Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
You can make this conversion explicit by writing `f _` or `f(_)(_)(_)(_)` instead of `f`.
```

There is one exception though as error message implies: if `f(0)` is placed in a functional context Scala will perform automatic eta-expansion, which means it will convert your method to a function:

```
scala> val fl: (Int => (Double => (Double => Double))) = f(0)
fl: Int => (Double => (Double => Double)) = $$Lambda$1342/937956960@43c1614
```

where eta-expansion means literally this:

```
scala> val fl: (Int => (Double => (Double => Double))) = (b => (c => (d => f(0)(b)(c)(d))))
fl: Int => (Double => (Double => Double)) = $$Lambda$1353/799716194@52048150
```

Another (explicit) way to convert a method to a curried function is by using placeholder (which will give you correct types right away):

```
scala> f _
res11: Int => (Int => (Double => (Double => Double))) = $$Lambda$1354/1675405592@4fa649d8

scala> f(0) _
res12: Int => (Double => (Double => Double)) = $$Lambda$1355/1947050122@ba9f744
```

Also be aware that:

```
def g: Int => (Double => (Double => Double)) = f(0)
```

is in fact

```
def g: Int => (Double => (Double => Double)) = (b => (c => (d => f(0)(b)(c)(d))))
```

i.e. it's a method `g`, which creates a function on the fly and returns it. So `g(0)` means "call method `g` without parameters, get back a function and apply it to `0`".